# Setting of Angular CLI node_modules folder pointer

Tags: angular-cli

When I import components in Angular2 CLI component I start like:

```
import { someComponent } from '@angular/core'; // comes from /node-modules
```

**Question:** If I may need to rename /node-modules folder to let's say /funky-modules and still have a working properly app, what should I do ? (If node modules folder name is custom-settable at all )